# C program that creates a process that it is blocked till its termination

Tags: c, linux

How do I create a process in C and play with it's state?

- I would like to know how to create a process.
- I would like to know how to put this process in Blocked state.
- I would like to know how to put this process in a Zombie state.

A guide on how to work with processes on C would be helpfull I just can't find it around. This way I could answer those questions myself.

I've been playing around with ps to see the state of a process but dont really know how to start.

Am working on Linux, sorry for my English.

Comment: `int main() { while(1); return 0; }`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You want the Linux equivalent of Windows `CREATE_SUSPENDED` which may very well not exist.

Comment: @H2CO3 Nope, that's not it.

Comment: Well, my C its not very good, I know Java but am starting with C. The thing is that I cant find a guide on how to change processes states in C. Thats why im asking.

Comment: I want a pony for Christmas. Seriously though, I know English is not your first language, but "I want" comes across as being a little impolite. Try "I would like" instead. Also, this is not the place for learning C process programming. Use a textbook for that. Or one of the millions of places on the web that would teach you it.

Comment: Okey, I changed the post since it's a direct question on "how to do something" and it sounds unpolite.

Comment: Some advice for a guide is what I would like to get, thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is where you come to get expert advice. It's not a place to come to get other people to do websearch for you.

Comment: okey, I just read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq I suppose it's not a good question. I've been searching around and I can find tons of things about processes but no guide on how to do it in **C**.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I didnt know it wasnt the place.

Comment: You could easily type in Google, "Create a process in C Linux", and get a ton of results, so why are you asking us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a child process using fork() - your program itself runs in a process anyway

Put process in "blocked" state:- use sleep() or issue a blocking write() - read manpages for more info - dunno what exactly you mean by 'blocked' here

Creating a zombie - fork() and then exit the program. You can "see" the zombie from ps

Comment: by blocked I mean: Process engages in activity with unknown duration, i.e. waiting for some event in the future. Sample events:
"I/O operation finished" or "message received from other
process". Engagement via OS call.

Answer (score 2):

if you throw out your understanding of typical parent child processes, it becomes simple

```
childpid=fork();
switch (childpid){
case 0 : //normally considered the child, but we will use it to continue on
     finish_program();
     return(0);
case -1 : //error occurred
default : //normally considered the parent, but our "blocked" process
     wait(childpid); //waits for the child process to terminate
     dostuff();
}
```

the parent is blocked until the child terminates

normally you would use semaphores and shared memory to block a process, but this is a good start

Comment: @Rkan - I left off the includes for brevity: #include <unistd.h>, #include <sys/types.h>, #include <sys/wait.h> and dostuff, finish_program are just place holders

Answer (score 1):

@user1869399 - I think you asked a very good question, and I think Bug Catcher gave a very good answer.

Key to Bug Catcher's suggestion about creating a "zombie" is forking a process without "cleaning up" after it exits (i.e. failing to call "waitpid()").

Here is a very good link on Linux process states:

- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html

Also, look at the "notes" section in the "man page" for waitpid():

- http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/wait.2.html

Comment: Thanks, Am starting with process states and only know hot to fork and do some little thinks. Your answer was usefull.